# constraint check range float

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I've got a problem with my sql code (working with oracle).

I'm triyng to make a constraint with body height, which should be between 1,0 and 2,4. The data type is a float. The decimal place is divided with a comma.
This ist the code:

```
alter table tableName
add constraint check_height
check (columnName between 1,0 and 2,4);
```

I tried to divide the decimal places in the code (I can't change the decimal place holder in the data list) with comma and points, I also tried to change the range and to show the range with < >. Nothing worked so far. Has anyone an idea what I am missing?

The error message is: 'check constraint violated'.

cheers

Comment: Do you have existing data in the table that violates the constraint you're trying to add? If you do, you'll need to decide whether to keep it or fix it; you can make the constraint ignore existing data if you want to.

Comment: yes. that was the problem. I haven't seen it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have data in your table with values that would violate the constraint, then you can't create it with the default `validate` clause:

```
create table tableName(columnName number);

insert into tablename (columnName) values(2.5);

alter table tableName
add constraint check_height
check (columnName between 1.0 and 2.4);

SQL Error: ORA-02293: cannot validate (STACKOVERFLOW.CHECK_HEIGHT) - check constraint violated
02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.
*Action:   Obvious
```

(My territory has `nls_numeric_characters='.,'`, so I've used `.` rather than `,`).

You can either correct or remove the invalid values, or allow the bad values to remain while only validating new data by specifying the [`novalidate` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52219):

```
alter table tableName
add constraint check_height
check (columnName between 1.0 and 2.4)
novalidate;

table TABLENAME altered.
```

New inserts or updates will still be validated, this only affects existing data.

Answer (score 3):

The decimal place should be separated with a dot `.` from the fractional part, not a comma, so:

```
alter table tableName
add constraint check_height
check (columnName between 1.0 and 2.4);
```

**Edit**

Regarding comments below - you *cannot* write a literal number in SQL and PL/SQL using a different decimal point separator than a dot `.` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#sthref216)). You can alter the session to set the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` parameter to change the decimal point separator, but it will only be taken into account when converting value of a different type to a number, for example, in the `TO_CHAR` function.

If you change the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, you can use a different separator than a dot `.` if you enclose the number in quotes (and that will cause an implicit conversion to a number, using the characters set in `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` to determine what is a decimal point, and what is a group separator). So, this will work:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ", ";

ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD CONSTRAINT check_height
CHECK (columnName BETWEEN '1,0' AND '2,4');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I already tried that but it doesn't work. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Hi @Przemyslaw, you should read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams144.htm#REFRN10126

Comment: @JeffreyKemp You are wrong. Altering session to change `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` doesn't change the fact that in both SQL and PLSQL languages it is the dot, not a comma, that is used to separate the decimal and fractional part of a literal number. `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is used in, for example, `TO_CHAR`. It would work as you say _if_ you specified the number in apostrophes, which the author of the question didn't do. You should read this: [Literals in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891)

Comment: The [globalisation support guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#sthref216) also says 'Numeric literals ... are part of the SQL language syntax and always use a dot as the decimal character and never contain a group separator'. But, the OP said 'I tried to divide the decimal places in the code ... with comma and points' and didn't say they got a different error (ORA-00905?), so I guess they quoted it and didn't show that in the question. Maybe your answer could mention the quoted version for completeness?

Comment: @AlexPoole The problem is that, the way Jeffrey Kemp wrote his comment, it is like pointing out a mistake in my answer stating that I don't know how to write a literal numerical value in PL/SQL, not that my answer wasn't helpful to the author... True, I looked at the code provided by the author and gave an answer without thoroughly reading the whole question. I can edit my answer to provide informaton about the quoted numbers. But, if Jeffrey Kemp meant that my answer is not helpful, I'll delete it. If he meant that you _can_ write literal number with `,`, then I'll let my answer stay.

Comment: I assumed the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER setting was being used until I tried it, went back to the docs, and realised the same thing. I'm agreeing with you, and I think it's still a useful answer if it explains why it should be a period (or quoted). Doesn't necessarily help the OP in this case but is relevant and will help someone else, I think.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks, I've edited my answer to show when you can use a different decimal separator and the way a number has to be given if that different separator should be used.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. For some reason I thought that setting had a bearing on PL/SQL code but of course it doesn't! Thanks Przemyslaw - and sorry. Eating humble pie tonight.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp No worries. And, if my answer to your comment sounded anyhow rude, then I'm sorry too, I didn't mean it like that. Cheers.